# Не работает маска ввода телефона. Как можно исправить данную проблему

Tags: javascript, html

[фрагмент кода](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmPSC.png)

[image: Библиотека подключена, но, к сожалению, ничего не работает]

[image: Как выглядит]
Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Код нужно вставлять текстом, а ошибку следует расписать подробнее.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас в консоли будет ошибка о том что нет такой функции в Jquery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Нужно подключить:)

Ну а если подключили все правильно тогда нужно еще добавить name="phone-number"!!!

```
  <input type=text class = "mask-phone form-control" placeholder="Номер телефона" name="phone-number"/>
```

Надеюсь все понятно:)